# How to update database using Windows Form data grid? (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, sql-update

When I drag the table from DataSet onto my Windows Form, a bindingNavigator and a dataGridView is created by default. Now when I run the project, add rows in the dataGridView, save it before exiting, and then re-run the project the added rows are there, but when I go to Server Explorer to view the Table Data, those rows aren't there in the Database.

On searching, I found that Visual Studio creates a copy of my database in the /bin/Debug folder, and performs all the changes in that copy of database. Is there a way to ensure that the new copy is created in the Project Directory so that older copy is modified instead of creating it in another directory? Or any other way to update the original Database?

p.s. Changing the 'Copy to Output Directory' property of Database to 'Do not copy' did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your Database using SqlAdapter.

```
// load data
if(ds != null)
        ds.Clear();
adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select id,title, description from testtable", con);
ds = new DataSet();
adap.Fill(ds);
dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];


// perform update
SqlCommandBuilder com = new SqlCommandBuilder(adap);
foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        dr["title"] = txtTitle.Text;
adap.Update(ds);
```

hope this helps

Comment: At the moment the code written by default is:

// TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.emp' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
`code`            this.empTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.emp);

// And this piece of code is saving the data:
            this.Validate();
            this.empBindingSource.EndEdit();
             this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.database1DataSet);

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

When you were creating your DataSet, did you uncheck the "Enable local database caching"  checkbox on the "Data Source Configuration Wizard" screen?

Comment: Yes, I did uncheck it. In fact it was unchecked by default.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Binding. You could use **Application Settings**. Just an XML File is written!